# Adding focus state to carousel thumbnails on selections

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, focus, carousel

I have a carousel with 6 thumbnails. The thumbnails have a border when hovered over, but when selected, the border disappears. I have tried all sorts of variation of active/hover/etc and can't seem to get the border to stay. Perhaps I can adjust the jQuery? I've pasted some code below, thanks!

```
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 15000
    });

    $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

    //Handles the carousel thumbnails
   $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
        var id = this.id.substr(this.id.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
        var id = parseInt(id);
        $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
    });


    // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
    $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
             var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
            $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
    });
});
    </script>
```

And here is the HTML for the carousel:

```
        <div class="container">
   <h2 id="smallH2HR" style="color: #0e4164; margin-bottom: 30px;">Examples of findings</h2>
    <div id="main_area">
            <!-- Slider -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" id="slider">
                    <!-- Top part of the slider -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8" id="carousel-bounding-box">
                            <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                                <!-- Carousel items -->
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                                    <img src="img/Graph_Example.png"></div>

                                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                                    <img src="img/Graph_Example.png"></div>

                                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                                    <img src="img/Graph_Example.png"></div>

                                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                                    <img src="img/Graph_Example.png"></div>

                                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                                    <img src="img/Graph_Example.png"></div>

                                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
                                    <img src="img/Graph_Example.png"></div>
                                </div><!-- Carousel nav -->
                                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="color: #2072b5;"></span>                                       
                                </a>
                                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="color: #2072b5;"></span>                                       
                                </a>                                
                                </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-4" id="carousel-text" style="background-color: #FCFCFC; border: 1px solid #F1F1F1; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 10px 0px 0px #eeaa30; -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 10px 0px 0px #eeaa30; box-shadow:inset 0px 7px 0px 0px #eeaa30, 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);"></div>

                        <div id="slide-content" style="display: none;">
                            <div id="slide-content-0">
                                <h2 style="margin-top: 20px;">Example One</h2>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam.</p>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Ut vulputate eros sed felis sodales nec vulputate justo hendrerit. Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit.</p>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam.</p>
                            </div>

                            <div id="slide-content-1">
                                <h2 style="margin-top: 20px;">Example Two</h2>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam.</p>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Ut vulputate eros sed felis sodales nec vulputate justo hendrerit. Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit.</p>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam.</p>
                            </div>

                            <div id="slide-content-2">
                                <h2 style="margin-top: 20px;">Example Three</h2>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam.</p>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Ut vulputate eros sed felis sodales nec vulputate justo hendrerit. Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit.</p>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam.</p>
                            </div>

                            <div id="slide-content-3">
                                <h2 style="margin-top: 20px;">Example Four</h2>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam.</p>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Ut vulputate eros sed felis sodales nec vulputate justo hendrerit. Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit.</p>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam.</p>
                            </div>

                            <div id="slide-content-4">
                                <h2 style="margin-top: 20px;">Example Five</h2>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam.</p>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Ut vulputate eros sed felis sodales nec vulputate justo hendrerit. Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit.</p>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam.</p>
                            </div>

                            <div id="slide-content-5">
                                <h2 style="margin-top: 20px;">Example Six</h2>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam.</p>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Ut vulputate eros sed felis sodales nec vulputate justo hendrerit. Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit.</p>
                                <p>Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--/Slider-->

            <div class="row hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs">
                    <!-- Bottom switcher of slider -->
                    <ul class="hide-bullets">
                        <li class="col-sm-2">
                            <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-0"><img src="img/Graph_Example_Thumb.png"></a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-sm-2">
                            <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="img/Graph_Example_Thumb.png"></a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-sm-2">
                            <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-2"><img src="img/Graph_Example_Thumb.png"></a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-sm-2">
                            <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-3"><img src="img/Graph_Example_Thumb.png"></a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-sm-2">
                            <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="img/Graph_Example_Thumb.png"></a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-sm-2">
                            <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-5"><img src="img/Graph_Example_Thumb.png"></a>
                            <div style="margin-top: -20px;">Opiods</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>                 
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Check out this https://codepen.io/srkimir/pen/mGbrf

Comment: It would be useful to see your HTML as well, so we can better assess where the issue might be.

Comment: Hi Robert - I have added my HTML. Thanks!

Comment: @pradeepRajput your solution worked! Thank you!